# DensityPlot3D with clear division negative/positive value but also value dependent

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

It is easy to obtain a clear positive/negative boundary, with, exemplary

```
ColorFunction -> Function[{f}, If[f > 0, Red, Blue]]
```

Do you have an idea how I can define a color function to get a clear division negative/positive value but also some info about the value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When posting a question, provide a concrete example and the code used to demonstrate the issue.

One approach to clearly delineate the boundary is to use [`ContourPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html) for the boundary

```
Show[
 DensityPlot3D[x y z,
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic],
 ContourPlot3D[x y z == 0,
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
  ContourStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Whether one of the pictures satisfied you requirement?

```
fig1 = DensityPlot3D[x*y*z, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{f}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][f]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> True];
fig2 = DensityPlot3D[x*y*z, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{f}, If[f > 0, Red, Blue]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
fig3 = DensityPlot3D[x*y*z, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{f}, Blend[{Blue, Red}, f]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer [Bob Hanlon's approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259023/125) as it is both simple and flexible.
As an alternative approach we can also use a custom [`OpacityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpacityFunction.html) to modify default opacity at function values close to 0:

```
ClearAll[customOpacity]
customOpacity[op1_: Automatic, op2_: .5] := If[.75 - .001 <= # <= .75 + .001, op2, 
  If[9/22 <= -1. + 2.*#1 < 7/11, .01, op1 /. Automatic -> .3, 0] ]& @
    Rescale[#1, {0, 1}, {0.5, 1}] &
```

***Examples:***

```
DensityPlot3D[x y z, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, OpacityFunction -> customOpacity[]]
```

[image]

Use `OpacityFunction -> customOpacity[Automatic, 1]` to get

[image]

`OpacityFunction -> customOpacity[.5]` to get

[image]

Add the option `ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"` to get

[image]

We can also use a custom `ColorFunction`:

```
defaultColorFunction = "DefaultColorFunction" /. (Method /. 
     Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, DensityPlot3D]);

ClearAll[customColor]
customColor[cf1_: Automatic, cf2_: Red] :=
    If[.5 - .0001 <= # <= .5 + .0001, cf2, 
      (cf1 /. Automatic -> defaultColorFunction) @ # ] &  ;


DensityPlot3D[x y z, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> customColor[], 
 OpacityFunction -> customOpacity[]]
```

[image]

Use `ColorFunction -> customColor[ColorData["Rainbow"]]` to get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Making a custom plotting function based on [Bob Hanlon's method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259023/125) combining `DensityPlot3D` and `ContourPlot3D`:

```
ClearAll[densityPlot3DwithContours]

SetAttributes[densityPlot3DwContours, HoldAll]

densityPlot3DwContours[f_, r1:{_,_,_}, r2:{_,_,_}, r3:{_,_,_}, o:OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Show[DensityPlot3D[f, r1, r2, r3, 
   Evaluate@FilterRules[{o}, Options[DensityPlot3D]]], 
  ContourPlot3D[f, r1, r2, r3, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   Evaluate @ FilterRules[DeleteCases[ColorFunction -> _]@{o}, 
     Options[ContourPlot3D]], 
   Contours -> {{0., Opacity[.3, Red]}}, 
   ContourStyle -> Automatic,
   Mesh -> None, 
   BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> 70]]
```

***Examples:***

```
densityPlot3DwContours[x y z, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, "StyledContours" -> {{0, Red}}]]
```

[image]

```
densityPlot3DwContours[x y z, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 Contours -> Thread[{{-.2, .1}, Opacity[.3, #] & /@ {Red, Green}}], 
 PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[Automatic, "StyledContours" -> Thread[{{-.2, .1}, {Red, Green}}]]]
```

[image]